# Initialize jOOQ with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jooq

We have a problem using jOOQ in a SpringBoot (1.3.3.RELEASE) application because it seems that jOOQ is not initialized (we don't see the ascii-art logo) until the first query is executed. This shouldn't be a problem but in our use case it is. So we're looking for a way to initialize jOOQ during the startup of the application.

What we've done is just create the following bean that is executed automatically by Spring once the application context has been created and just execute a query to initialize jOOQ.

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner runner(DSLContext create) {
    new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            create.fetchCount(create.select(BLACKBOX))
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's the problem that is caused by late initialisation of jOOQ? Btw: Your idea looks fine, you could set that as an answer...

Comment: The _problem_ is because we have an AOP that intercept the execution of some Spring services and log that execution as an audit trail. The module that logs them receive the requests using RabbitMQ and has a timeout of 1 second. The problem is the initialization of jOOQ takes a little bit more than that and the request fails and is rejected by Rabbit. Now, with the workaround it works fine :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, the class loading of all the generated classes can take a while, if you have a large schema. Running an actual query is the best way to solve this. You could even run a cheaper query: `create.fetchExists(BLACKBOX)`

Comment: We've finally used this: `create.selectOne().fetch()`

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as Lukas said, that's an answer:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner runner(DSLContext create) {
    new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            create.selectOne().fetch()
        }
    }
}
```